# Python-Eve: Prevent inserting duplicates without using unique fields

Tags: python, duplicates, eve, objectid

I am trying to prevent inserting duplicate documents by the following approach:

1. Get a list of all documents from the desired endpoint which will contain all the documents in JSON-format. This list is called `available_docs`.
2. Use a `pre_POST_<endpoint>` hook in order to handle the request before inserting to the data. I am not using the `on_insert` hook since I need to do this before validation.
3. Since we can access the `request` object use `request.json` to get the payload JSON-formatted
4. Check if `request.json` is already contained in `available_docs`
5. Insert new document if it's not a duplicate only, abort otherwise.

Using this approach I got the following snippet:

```
def check_duplicate(request):
    if not request.json in available_sims:
        print('Not a duplicate')
    else:
        print('Duplicate')
        flask.abort(422, description='Document is a duplicate and already in database.')
```

The `available_docs` list looks like this:

```
available_docs = [{'foo': ObjectId('565e12c58b724d7884cd02bb'), 'bar': [ObjectId('565e12c58b724d7884cd02b9'), ObjectId('565e12c58b724d7884cd02ba')]}]
```

The payload `request.json` looks like this:

```
{'foo': '565e12c58b724d7884cd02bb', 'bar': ['565e12c58b724d7884cd02b9', '565e12c58b724d7884cd02ba']}
```

As you can see, the only difference between the document which was passed to the API and the document already stored in the DB is the datatype of the IDs. Due to that fact, the `if`-statement in my above snippet evaluates to `True` and judges the document to be inserted not being a duplicate whereas it definitely is a duplicate.

Is there a way to check if a passed document is already in the database? I am not able to use unique fields since the combination of all document fields needs to be unique only. There is an unique identifier (which I left out in this example), but this is not suitable for the desired comparison since it is kind of a time stamp.

I think something like casting the given IDs at the keys `foo` and `bar` as `ObjectIDs` would do the trick, but I do not know how to to this since I do not know where to get the datatype `ObjectID` from.

Comment: Even if it was the same datatype the code would still fail because these are different objects. If you want to consider them as similar you'll have to create a comparison function and use it instead of doing `if not request.json in available_sims`

Comment: I got your point about the different objects (like e.g. referencing). However something like `a = {'albert': 2015}
l = []
l.append(a)
b = {'albert': 2015}
print(b in l)` evaluates to `True`. So this approach came in my mind.

Comment: But you're dealing with objects not numbers, see the following example which will better reflect your situation: https://gist.github.com/alfasin/32a50c4817ebf8b390fd

Comment: That's true. Since the ObjectIDs are unique I thought comparing those to each other (as strings) would to the job. I am still thinking that this idea will do the trick, but my approach is somehow wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You approach would be **much** slower than setting a unique rule for the field.

Since, from your example, you are going to compare objectids, can't you simply use those as the `_id` field for the collection? In Mongo (and Eve of course) that field is unique by default. Actually, you typically don't even define it. You would not need to do anything at all, as a POST of a document with an already existing id would fail right away.

If you can't go that way (maybe you need to compare a different objectid field and still, for some reason, you can't simply set a `unique` rule for the field), I would look at querying the db for the field value instead than getting all the documents from the db and then scanning them sequentially in code. Something like `db.find({db_field: new_document_field_value})`. If that returns true, new document is a duplicate. Make sure `db_field` is indexed (which usually holds true also for fields tagged with `unique` rule)

**EDIT after the comments**. A trivial implementation would probable be something like this:

```
def pre_POST_callback(resource, request):
    # retrieve mongodb collection using eve connection
    docs = app.data.driver.db['docs']

    if docs.find_one({'foo': <value>}):
        flask.abort(422, description='Document is a duplicate and already in database.')


app = Eve()
app.run()
```

Comment: So I would do the `db.find({db_field: new_document_field_value})` query using eve's `?where={db_field: new_document_field_value}` approach, wouldn't I?

Comment: Or is there a way to do this internally since I intend checking duplicates with a pre_POST hook? Can I somehow use eve's underlying pymongo instance? How can I ensure that indexing is active?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach on preventing duplicate records:

`def on_insert_subscription(items):
    c_subscription = app.data.driver.db['subscription']
    user = decode_token()
    if user:
        for item in items:
            if c_subscription.find_one({
                'topic': ObjectId(item['topic']),
                'client': ObjectId(user['user_id'])
            }):
                abort(422, description="Client already subscribed to this topic")
            else:
                item['client'] = ObjectId(user['user_id'])
    else:
        abort(401, description='Please provide proper credentials')`

What I'm doing here is creating subscriptions for clients. If a client is already subscribed to a topic I throw 422.
Note: the client ID is decoded from the JWT token.